# How do I get initial admin password for jenkins on Mac?

Tags: macos, jenkins

I installed jenkins by downloading jenkins-2.2.pkg. After the installation is complete, Chrome auto-connected to `http://localhost:8080/login?from=%2F` and I see the following message:

> **Unlock Jenkins**
> To ensure Jenkins is securely set up by the administrator, a password has been written to the log (not sure where to find it?) and this file on the server:
>
> */Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/secrets/initialAdminPassword*
>
> Please copy the password from either location and paste it below.

But I don't have access to secrets folder on my Mac book even when I'm the Admin user.

Please help me on how to find the initial admin password?

Comment: Who owns the `/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/secrets` folder? It might be sufficient to run a `chown` on it.

Comment: How do I find out on who is owning the folder? And what is chown?

Comment: I found the solution. Thank you.

Comment: If you could, please add the solution as an answer and accept it.

Comment: Add the solution, please.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

1. Navigate to this folder `/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home`
2. Right click on `secrets/` folder and select "Get Info"
3. Scroll down to the right bottom corner of the pop up window and click on the lock image > enter your password > ok
4. Click on the "+" at the left bottom corner of the pop up window and add the user
   4.5 Click on Settings icon - left bottom and Apply changes.
5. Open the "secrets" folder and find the `initialAdminPassword` file to get the initial admin password. If you don't have permission to the file, you need to right click on the file and select "Get Info" then repeat step 3 and 4 above to access the file.

Comment: What to do if Jenkins did not create it?

Answer (score 35):

Try it

```
sudo cat /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/secrets/initialAdminPassword
```

and copy the password.

Answer (score 30):

If you have installed Jenkins through `HomeBrew`, check

`sudo cat /Users/$(whoami)/.jenkins/secrets/initialAdminPassword`

Comment: I used brew, i don't have .jenkins file. @Prashanth Sams

Comment: it is not visible, but there are for me

Comment: For those who can't able to view .jenkins press Command+Shift+. (dot). Now, you can view all hidden files.

Answer (score 7):

I install jenkins by img, use this command to cat password

```
sudo cat /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/secrets/initialAdminPassword
```

Comment: In my case, the path is on my personal folder, not Shared, this for initial user-password value

Answer (score 4):

If you have installed Jenkins using Docker and you are not able to find the password using the command :

```
$ sudo cat /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/secrets/initialAdminPassword
```

Then do following steps :

1. Type in your command prompt : `docker ps`
2. Find the running containerID
3. Type `docker exec -it <containerID> bash`
4. Type `cd /var/jenkins_home/secrets`
5. Type `cat initialAdminPassword`

Comment: Thank you adityaatri  it worked , for windows I had to change the command to docker exec -it 0a15a836309a /bin/bash in cmd  window .

Answer (score 2):

The current user might not have permissions to Secrets folder to access the initialAdminPassword file. So give permission by selecting "Secrets" folder by  CMD+ i which launches a new screen and then unlock and then provide required permissions.

[Locked file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8ipy.png)

[Unlocked and Access to initialAdminPassword file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qe9hY.png)

Answer (score 2):

Note if you are running Homestead / Vagrant and Ubuntu

```
sudo cat /var/lib/jenkins/secrets/initialAdminPassword
```

Answer (score 2):

If you homebrew installed JENKINS, then by default, JENKINS_HOME is at ~/.jenkins 
This is also the location where you will find you will find your initial password inside the secrets folder.

So: cd ~/.jenkins
cd secrets
open initialAdminPassword

Answer (score 2):

If you are using jenkins image from dockerhub repo and create a container then you can get the initial password using:

```
$ sudo docker exec jenkins_containerid cat /var/lib/jenkins/secrets/initialAdminPassword
```

OR if installing from jenkins.io docs (https://jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/):

```
$ sudo docker exec jenkins_containerid cat /var/jenkins_home/secrets/initialAdminPassword
```

OR
you can see the docker logs of container

```
$ sudo docker logs jenkinscontainerID
```

Answer (score 1):

ref:http://www.cimgf.com/2015/05/26/setting-up-jenkins-ci-on-a-mac-2/

1. Make the Jenkins user an admin:  sudo dseditgroup -o edit -a jenkins -t user admin
2. Add the Jenkins user to the developer group: sudo dscl . append /Groups/_developer GroupMembership jenkins
3. Make the Jenkins user automatically login when the computer is restarted:

Answer (score 1):

For mac M1 on BigSur Os, the path I got is:

```
~/.jenkins/secrets
```

https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/macos/

if not there look into
/Users/Aakash~/.jenkins/secerts

Answer (score 1):

Either get inside your docker machine or you can check in the  mount you created in local storage for your jenkins.
if inside docker machine---->

1. search for jenkins_home(probably inside /var)
2. Inside jenkins_home/secrets/-----> open this file "initialAdminPassword"

if looking in local

1. go to your mount cd /(mount_name)/jenkins_home/

rest steps are same as above.

Answer (score 0):

To unlock Jenkins, use this command in your terminal:

```
$ sudo cat /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/secrets/initialAdminPassword
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was looking for this on MY MAC, but what you actually have to do is ssh to your docker container.

```
docker ps
```

which will display the containers, then copy the id of the container you created,

then do

```
docker exec -it <paste-id-here> /bin/bash
```

If that's successful, you will see your terminal change to, then you can run:

```
cat
```

Answer (score 0):

As per Official Documentation they recommend Homebrew Installer. So if you did Homebrew Installer then check when the installation time it is printed in console or check in the current user jenkins folder.Cmd given below.

sudo cat /Users/$(whoami)/.jenkins/secrets/initialAdminPassword

Answer (score 0):

Open your terminal and type:

```
sudo cat /var/lib/jenkins/secrets/initialAdminPassword (or the path provided on the website opened).
```

I tried it from my Ec2 Amazon Instance and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

None of these answers had enough information for me (installed via homebrew on mac). I did not have an initialAdminPassword file. Turns out it was because I ran the executable as a normal user. What I had to do was execute Jenkins from command line using `sudo`:

```
sudo jenkins
```

When I did that, I saw the following:

```
*************************************************************
*************************************************************
*************************************************************

Jenkins initial setup is required. An admin user has been created and a password generated.
Please use the following password to proceed to installation:

dee34d2b00804123456757ec46d3beef

This may also be found at: /var/root/.jenkins/secrets/initialAdminPassword

*************************************************************
*************************************************************
*************************************************************
```

Then I just pointed my browser to http://localhost:8080/ and filled out the form displayed there, at which time I could start installing plugins and actually using Jenkins.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

1.Double tap on finder select "Go to folder"  enter /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home

2.Check the "secret" folder , right click and select "get info"

3.Click on "lock" icon and enter admin password and make change in view type (change into user view) after this your  folder is accessible .

4.Do same for password text file also