# jenkins pluginManager 'Check Now' 'unable to find valid certification' error

Tags: jenkins, ssh, sslhandshakeexception, pkix

I just installed a new jenkins 2.77 instance on my Windows machine, running Java 1.8.0 #60.

I was expecting there to be some default plugins but it seems like none were installed when the instance was created.

When I go to check the available plugins tab, it reads:

`Update information obtained: N/A ago`

When I click on the 'Check now' button, I get an error with the following stack trace:

Stack trace:

```
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
Caused: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)
Caused: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.model.DownloadService.loadJSON(DownloadService.java:167)
    at hudson.model.UpdateSite.updateDirectlyNow(UpdateSite.java:190)
    at hudson.PluginManager.doCheckUpdatesServer(PluginManager.java:1629)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.invokeWithArguments(Unknown Source)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$MethodFunction.invoke(Function.java:343)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.interceptor.RequirePOST$Processor.invoke(RequirePOST.java:52)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.PreInvokeInterceptedFunction.invoke(PreInvokeInterceptedFunction.java:26)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:184)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:117)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$1.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:129)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:715)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:845)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$2.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:186)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:715)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:845)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:649)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:238)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:841)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1650)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:135)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)
    at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
    at hudson.security.UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.java:51)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at jenkins.security.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:117)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilter(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:125)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilter(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:142)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:271)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at jenkins.security.BasicHeaderProcessor.doFilter(BasicHeaderProcessor.java:92)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)
    at hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:67)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:90)
    at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)
    at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.java:30)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:533)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:524)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1253)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:166)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1155)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:317)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:279)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:124)
    at winstone.BoundedExecutorService$1.run(BoundedExecutorService.java:77)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21076179/pkix-path-building-failed-and-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requ), I gather that I need to do some sort of key or ssh configuration but I'm not clear on all of the variables to use as they apply to this specific error.

How can I fix this issue?

**Update 2017-09-11:**

- I uninstalled Java and then installed the latest Java, 1.8.0 #44.
- I uninstalled Jenkins and deleted the folder in Program Files.
- I installed Jenkins 2.77

This time in the setup wizard I noticed a page informing me that Jenkins was offline.

I'm not sure what it means because I can connect to the internet. I gather that for whatever reason Jenkins cannot.

I am very sure now that when I originally installed Jenkins I saw this page and chose to skip plugin installation. It's likely that the "Jenkins is offline" message is related to the "unable to find valid certification path to requested target".

There seems to be a similar issue in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42408703/why-does-jenkins-say-this-jenkins-instance-appears-to-be-offline).

Answer (score 11):

Jenkins 2.77 [changed](https://jenkins.io/changelog/#v2.77) the default URL of the Update Centre (UC) to use `https://` rather than `http://`.

The Jenkins UC uses an SSL certificate from [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/), but the root certificates that Let's Encrypt certificates depend on weren't added to Java 8 until [update 101](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/certificate-compatibility/#known-compatible).

Upgrade your Java installation from 8u60 to at least 8u101, and it should work as expected.

Comment: I updated Java but had no luck. More details are in an update to my OP. What do you think about the offline message in the setup and do you think it is related?

Comment: @kraftydevil Yes, if you have the same issue with certificates during the setup wizard, it will tell you that Jenkins is offline. If you're sure Jenkins is running with the latest version of Java 8, you'd need to take a look at the Jenkins logs and file an issue: https://jenkins.io/redirect/report-an-issue/

Answer (score 8):

I run into this intermittently on Jenkins installs. I've found two simple approaches that avoid fiddling around with security certificates all day.

**skip-security-check plugin**

First, you can install the [skip-security-check plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Skip+Certificate+Check+plugin) which I believe is packaged with Jenkins, so you don't need to reach out to download it.

**Just use http**

The second and simplest is to just go to the Jenkins Download Manager page in the admin console and update the URL so that the preamble is http instead of http**s**.

**[image: Just go back to http]**

I wrote a quick article on the topic, but the tl'dr is that you can simply change the url back to http://

[Fix SunCertPathBuilderException in Jenkins](https://www.theserverside.com/blog/Coffee-Talk-Java-News-Stories-and-Opinions/SunCertPathBuilderException-fix-for-Jenkins-plugin-download)

Comment: This is not a good answer. Sorry to have to downvote but disabling security cannot be considered a solution.

Comment: When you secure a resource, you must secure it for a reason. Securing everything just for the sake of securing it doesn't make sense. I can't think of any http based security exploit that is possible when updating a Jenkins plugin, nor do I know of any secure data sent across the network during an update. As such, I'd assert that there is no sensible reason to secure a connection that has no reason to be secured.

Comment: Well, if that were true, then they would not have used HTTPS to begin with. I mean I'm well aware of the fact that a lot of websites could potentially work without HTTPS but the reality there's not reason not to use TLS in 2020 with most of the work being automated by Let's encrypt. I'm not saying that disabling HTTPS would not solve the OP's issue but it's not a solution, it's a workaround and should be treated as such.

Answer (score 2):

The correct solution is to NOT disable the certificate checks as a lot people have suggested but rather to add the website certificate to the Java keystore instead.

I'll list my own guide below which should work for Linux. I suspect the same imports will work in Windows as the keytool is bundled with Java but you're on your own when it comes to any openssl commands.

Download all required certificates in the chain (this is a command I found on SO, I can't find the link but it's not my own creation):

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -verify 5 -connect updates.jenkins-ci.org:443 < /dev/null | awk '/BEGIN/,/END/{ if(/BEGIN/){a++}; out="cert"a".crt"; print >out}' && for cert in *.crt; do newname=$(openssl x509 -noout -subject -in $cert | sed -n 's/^.*CN=\(.*\)$/\1/; s/[ ,.*]/_/g; s/__/_/g; s/^_//g;p').pem; mv $cert $newname; done
```

You should now have 2 files:

```
Let's_Encrypt_Authority_X3.pem
pkg_origin_jenkins_io.pem
```

Concatenate the 2 files:

```
cat "Let's_Encrypt_Authority_X3.pem" pkg_origin_jenkins_io.pem > full_chain.pem
```

This next step is useful as the Java keytool is picky and the openssl package will fix any spacing issues. I have seen the keytool import fail even though openssl claimed it was valid so don't skip this step:

```
openssl x509 -in full_chain.pem -out full_chain_sanitized.pem
```

Now comes the fun part. I assume your Jenkins instance is running with some of the following arguments:

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/applications/configuration/pki/keystore.jks 
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=GOOD_PASSWORD 
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/applications/configuration/pki/truststore.jks 
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=GOOD_PASSWORD
```

Also note that you might not be using the custom keystores. In that case, you could try to include the certificate in the default cacerts file instead. Check the next section for details. If you are using any truststores, you will have configured a password so enter it when prompted.

Now we can import the Jenkins plugin site certificate. Make sure to use your own keytool path as it will differ from my own.

```
/applications/java/latest/bin/keytool -trustcacerts  -import -v -alias pkg_jenkins_io_full_chain -file full_chain_sanitized.pem -keystore /applications/configuration/pki/keystore.jks

/applications/java/latest/bin/keytool -trustcacerts  -import -v -alias pkg_jenkins_io_full_chain -file full_chain_sanitized.pem -keystore /applications/configuration/pki/truststore.jks
```

Restart your Jenkins server and the plugin site should work. If it doesn't (or if you weren't using custom keystores to begin with), you could try adding the certificate to the Java cacerts file but this is usually frowned upon as it will get replaced during any updates. A better option might be to instead create a backup, include the certificate in the copy and run Jenkins with using the copy as a truststore.

Remember that the default password for the cacerts store is 'changeit'

```
cp /apps/java/latest/jre/lib/security/cacerts /apps/java/latest/jre/lib/security/cacerts_copy

# Add the certificate to the keystore
/applications/java/latest/bin/keytool -trustcacerts -import -v -alias pkg_jenkins_io_full_chain -file full_chain_sanitized.pem -keystore /apps/java/latest/jre/lib/security/cacerts_copy

# Add -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore= property to the Jenkins startup parameters, depending on your own OS.
# Just make sure to append it as such:
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/apps/java/latest/jre/lib/security/cacerts_copy
```

The https://stackoverflow.com/a/47316409/7569335 answer is good but it does not account for the custom keystore files scenario that I faced. Check it out as well as it has good info.

Answer (score 1):

This issue i had recently and the solution for Jenkins running on the Windows machine is to change the Java path in jenkins.xml configuration file - located at default path C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\

First find the location of Java on the Windows machine. In administrator command prompt run this

```
for %i in (java.exe) do @echo.   %~$PATH:i
```

On the Windows 2012 R2 server in question it returned:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe

Then stop jenkins service in services.msc

Then edit the jenkins.xml by commenting the default java path and entering the new one:

```
<!--executable>%BASE%\jre\bin\java</executable>-->
<executable>C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe</executable>
```

Finally start the jenkins service

Comment: The command to find the java path didn't work for me but specifying the full path to the java executable did. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the solution for this was to simply **disable my avast antivirus**, but apparently, it's something related to a firewall blocking some access.