# Why does Jenkins keep telling me it is offline?

Tags: jenkins

I am not getting option to install plugins in Jenkins. Instead getting two options Configure Proxy and Skip Plugin Installations.

[image]

Comment: Maybe duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42408703/why-does-jenkins-say-this-jenkins-instance-appears-to-be-offline

Comment: You may also take a look at http://alakbarv.azurewebsites.net/2017/09/12/jenkins-offline-problem-solved-on-windows/

Comment: From the machine that is running Jenkins, as the user that is running Jenkins, see if you can access this url using curl, or wget, or a browser: http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/update-center.json

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing these links i followed 1st link and got solution, In my case, it has something to do with SSL. I manage to fix it by editing /var/lib/jenkins/hudson.model.UpdateCenter.xml and change url to use http instead of https.

Comment: For demo or simple testing, windows could be the last alternative to host jenkins. For real environments, try to use Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Might be worth checking - I did a mistake myself and spent a day checking.

Just mention the IP, and not the complete address in Server field in jenkins while configuring proxy.

So, let us suppose your proxy is http://x.x.x.x:8080 - so just put x.x.x.x in server field.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins.jenkins,

Modify "hudson.model.UpdateCenter.xml" file by changing the URL property to "http"

Finally Open CMD with Admin privilege and run.

net stop jenkins

net start jenkins