# Jenkins 2.89.3 "This Jenkins instance appears to be offline"

Tags: java, macos, jenkins, offline

I have this problem that I can't seem to solve. Using macOS High Sierra.
I installed Jenkins on my MacBook and I tried to run it on my system but I get this error:
[Jenkins message window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCpOK.png)

I have tried the following:

- Updated JDK to Update 161 (latest)
- Navigated to: `/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/hudson.model.UpdateCenter.xml` and changed `https` to `http`
- Uninstalled and reinstalled Jenkins, I have also tried other versions of Jenkins.
- Restart Jenkins service through terminal.

Below is the error message when running `java -jar jenkins.war` in the terminal which I suspect is the source of the

> Jenkins appears to be offline

and I do not know how to solve this.

[Log file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrCxk.png)

Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you!

David

Comment: Please do not [post screenshots of error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question). Paste the text directly to your question and apply code formatting (the `{}` icon).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question, I assume that you used Internet connection to do a fresh Jenkins installation and the Jenkins service is started.

The error message points to SSL error. It seems that you have followed an answer in this forum [Why does Jenkins say "This Jenkins instance appears to be offline"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42408703/why-does-jenkins-say-this-jenkins-instance-appears-to-be-offline), but with no success.

When I had similar exception message I managed to fix it after importing self-signed certificate into JVM (Jenkins uses Java).

```
keytool -import -alias $ALIAS -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts -file $PATH_TO_PEM_FILE
```

More detailed information can be found here:
https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/217078498-PKIX-path-building-failed-error-message

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right, I got this question solved on reddit though. Thank you for your answer. I verified it.